# "PostSharp Extension initialization error" after update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, postsharp

I am using Visual Studio 2012.  I had installed PostSharp 4.0.41.  I downloaded and installed PostSharp 4.1.10.  When bringing up VS 2012 now, I get a "PostSharp Extension initialization error"  "Please, clean the component model cache and restart VisualStudio".

Deleting the ComponentModelCache directory and restarting VS2012 shows a dialog "Loading components" and then it returns to the same "PostSharp Extension Initialization error" dialog.

If I uninstall PostSharp via "Extensions and Updates" and delete the "ComponentModelCache" PostSharp is still installed and the initialization error dialog reappears, PostSharp is still in the VS 2012 main menu bar, but it is no longer in the "Extensions and Updates" box.

If I reinstall PostSharp 4.0.41, VS2012 starts cleanly, but I have not been able to update PostSharp.

fwiw, I am using a PostSharp Express license.

Any ideas on how to update PostSharp?

Thanks

Comment: What VS2012 version do you use? Please, could you file a problem here: http://support.sharpcrafters.com/dashboard?

Comment: Professional (Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4)  I am moving the question to the specified dashboard.  Thanks, Jakub!